# Find number of triangles formed by lines( given:angle along x-axis)

Tags: combinatorics, trigonometry, triangles

i came across this problem in a competitive coding class :

A number of lines (extending infinity) in both directions are drawn on a plane. the lines are specified by the angle (positive or negative) made with the x axis(in degrees,constrained to -89° to 90° ).

**the objective is to determine the number of triangles formed by the set of these lines.**

*An example:*

*If the lines are given with an angle of 10,70,30,30(with the x-axis) the figure looks like this*

[L1=10°,L2=70°,L3=30°,L4=30°](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFIEk.png)

here there are two triangles (L1,L2,L3 and L1,L2,L4).

Comment: Do you mean the maximum number of triangles? (since if all the lines pass through common point, the number of triangles obtained would be zero!)

Comment: Your image does not load for me.

Comment: @MrHolmes i have to determine how many triangles are formed by these lines , the lines can be of any number and i am given only the angles r.t. x-axis , also we may assume that the different lines are not coincident and that none of them are concurrent. im looking for the logic in solving this problem.

Comment: @RossMillikan try this link (https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUTTU.png)

Comment: I get the same black screen with a narrow white frame.  It is the same link.  I was going to paste it in because it takes a bit of reputation to post an image.

Comment: @RossMillikan sorry about that.The image looked really dull.I have updated the photo in the question  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFIEk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any set of three lines at different angles will form a triangle unless they pass through a common point.  If we exclude cases where three lines go through a point, count the number of lines at each angle. I will take an example where the angles are $-10,-5,0,10,10,10,20,20,30,40,50$.  We can represent this as $(1,1,1,3,2,1,1,1)$ because there are $3$ lines at $10$ and $2$ lines at $20$.

If all the lines were at different angles there would be ${11 \choose 3}=165$ triangles.  We need to subtract the number of ways to get two parallel lines and one nonparallel, which is ${3 \choose 2}\cdot 8+{2 \choose 2}\cdot 9=33$.  We then have to subtract the number of ways of getting three parallel lines, which is ${3\choose 3}=1$.  The answer is then $131$.

If there are $n_i$ lines at angle $i$ and $n=\sum_i n_i$ is the total number of lines, the number of triangles is
$${n \choose 3}-\sum_i \left((n-n_i){n_i \choose 2} -{n_i \choose 3}\right)$$

Comment: i didnt understand this second part of the formula ∑i((n−ni)(ni2)−(ni3))                               
  can u apply it in {10,70,30,30}

Comment: I applied it to my example, which I think shows it more clearly. For yours, the only one that has the combination not zero is $n_3=2$ because there are two lines at $30$.  $n-n_3=2, {2 \choose 2}=1$ and there are no $n_i \ge 3$, so the sum is $2$.  Finally we get ${4 \choose 3}-2\cdot 1=2$